# NMAP Favicon 2013

Tags: discussion, favicon

Did anyone else get the email from NMAP about their Favicon 2013 'map of the internet'?

You can see it at: http://nmap.org/favicon/

What I find impressive is that Stack Overflow is one of the largest sites.

- You can find Stack Overflow just to the right of the red http://yahoo.co.jp/ icon, just to the right of Facebook.
- Stack Exchange is a bit harder to find; it is between PayPal and Live Door slightly to the left and below centre.
- SuperUser is still harder; it is just to the bottom left of Linked In.
- ServerFault is also hard to find; it is near PayPal too, but in detail, just to the left of Pornhub and just below Bet365.

Ah well, it's slightly different from discussing hats.

Comment: That's... a lot of icons. o.o